# vscode don't close all django(python) processes when I click stop button

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

VSCode Version: 1.42.1

OS Version: Ubuntu 18.04

Steps to Reproduce:

Press Ctrl + F5 to run the django process.

Click "stop(Shift + F5)" button to stop all django process.

But there is still a process (pid 23069) that has not been closed.

And it's parent process become 1 from 23064

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

add --noreload to launch.json, Everything is ok now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Linux, You need press "Shift + F5" to stop the Debug.

I have provided a link in which, all shortcuts are giving in it for the vscode ( Linux)
[keyboard-shortcuts-linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf)

Comment: Press "ctrl + c" and I only get this '^C'. None of the processes was closed.

Comment: wait I will reach you in 5 mins

Comment: help can you provide me screen shot that

Comment: Because I tried on my vscode and it works perfectly fine

Comment: hey try 'shift + f5'

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my settings. I uninstall my vscode and remove all settings, and reinstall vscode, Everything is ok now! Thanks you for the useful information.